# Why value string is not being properly sent as json via api?

Tags: json, api, flutter, internal-server-error, http-put

Im trying to pass a string to an api method in flutter.

This is my api method format:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PutInterests(string value)
    { .....}
```

This is my flutter request knowing that value is a string:

```
 final response = await client.put(
  "http://"+base+":8070/api/Connectors",
    headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
    body:json.encode(value)
);
```

I am continuously getting internal server error (500).

Note that im sure the url is correct and there is no other put method in the controller. Also, the string received is either null or empty based on my code inside the api method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to test a request via postman? The 500 error means there is something wrong with the server side.

Comment: Tried it via swagger, working normally. @P4yam

Comment: I had a similar problem, if you use json.encode(string) it adds "" at the start and the end. Did you try to put into body directly the value ?

Comment: yes i did .. im getting an internal server error @StefanoMiceli

Comment: if you print(value) and then print(json.encode(value)) what are the differences?

Comment: value gives 1,2,3 , json.encode(value) gives "1,2,3,".I resolved this issue by putting my value in a class and sending it as an encoded model to my api method but didn't find a simpler solution :( @StefanoMiceli